# Select python version to execute from prompt

Tags: python, command-prompt, prompt

I have several python versions installed (and working properly on my machines). Isn't there a way to execute a specific version of python from the command line.

Say I want to use python 3.1. I am after something a ***SIMPLE COMMAND*** such as `python3.1` or `python31` that would be used as follows :`python3.1 setup.py install`, for instance.

[`pip` has `pip3.1` to install a library with the version 3.1 of python, specifically]

Comment: On Linux, you'd normally have the executables in `/usr/bin/`. Usually, the name of the executables is `python3.4`, `python2.7`...etc so you should already be able to use them in the format you're asking for without any changes.

Comment: You can also manipulate your `$PATH` just prior to executing the Python code, so that the path to the particular Python version you use is at the front of `$PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, but the best approach varies depending on the OS you're using. For Windows, you want the `py` launcher, for which instructions are [here](http://testerstories.com/2014/06/multiple-versions-of-python-on-windows/). For Mac OS X and Linux, you could use something like [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv). Of course, you could always build your own solution using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to go about this.  As Sir_FZ pointed out, the executables are already named `python2.7`, etc, so what you want already exists.  If for some really odd reason you have more than one python2.7 in your `$PATH`, you can explicitly call `/my/other/python2.7` etc.  If you're lazy, you can even create alias's `alias p2=/my/other/python2.7` and then you can call `p2 setup.py install`

If you're going to be doing this for more than a day, I'd suggest following one of Sagar's links.